# Insert hyphen into number

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to convert:

```
"890414.14.1422, 900515141092, 950616-12-5414"
```

to:

```
"890414-14-1422, 900515-14-1092, 950616-12-5414"
```

How can I achieve it?

I tried:

```
def format_ids(string)
  string.gsub(/(\d{6})[.-](\d{2})[.-](\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3')
end

format_ids("890414.14.1422, 900515141092, 950616-12-5414")
# => "890414-14-1422, 900515141092, 950616-12-5414"
```

Comment: I modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should make the delimiters in the input string *non mandatory*:

```
- string.gsub(/(\d{6})[.-](\d{2})[.-](\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3')
+ string.gsub(/(\d{6})[.-]?(\d{2})[.-]?(\d{4})/, '\1-\2-\3')
```

Note question marks after the delimiters, they do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "890414.14.1422, 900515141092, 950616-12-5414"
```

```
r = /
    (            # begin capture group 1
      \.         # match a period
      |          # or
      (?<=\d{6}) # match after 6 digits (positive lookbehind)
      (?=\d{6})  # match before 6 digits (positive lookahead)
      |          # or
      (?<=\d{8}) # match after 8 digits (positive lookbehind)
      (?=\d{4})  # match before 4 digits (positive lookahead)
    )            # end capture group 1
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
str.gsub(r,'-')
  #=> "890414-14-1422, 900515-14-1092, 950616-12-5414"
```

This regular expression is conventionally (not free-spacing mode) written as follows:

```
/(\.|(?<=\d{6})(?=\d{6})|(?<=\d{8})(?=\d{4}))/
```

Note that `(?<=\d{6})` and `(?=\d{6})` match a position *between* two consecutive spaces that has a width of zero, as do `(?<=\d{8})` and `(?=\d{4})`.

Comment: If `format_ids` is supposed to format numbers in a larger text, `delete('.-')` might delete too much (i.e. other periods and hyphens).